ANTLR spaces management
I'm trying to understand how does ANTLRv4 works. I took the C example available in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4 and I tried to test some inputs to the parser (in Python)
Here is the Python code I use:
import antlr4
import language.CLexer
import language.CParser
import language.CListener

INPUT = """constint test = 3 ;"""

class CListener(language.CListener.CListener):
    def enterCompilationUnit(self, ctx):
        for child in ctx.getChildren():
            print(child.getText(), end="")
        print("")


lexer = language.CLexer.CLexer(antlr4.InputStream(INPUT))
stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)

# Create the parser and parse the request.
parser = language.CParser.CParser(stream)
tree = parser.compilationUnit()

printer = CListener()
walker = antlr4.ParseTreeWalker()
walker.walk(printer, tree)

(I generated the grammar files in the folder language)
I tried to test the grammar with some inputs. int test = 3 ; is valid (no error printed).
And then, I tried: constint test = 3 ; (without the space between const and int). And this doesn't print an error message.
But if I remove the final semi-colon by testing const int test = 3, then I got an error message.
Why is the constint accepted (this is not accepted by C language)?

The grammar you're using defines typedefName: Identifier without any semantic predicate to check whether the given name has actually been typedefed. This will lead to misparses in some cases (related to ambiguities between casts and function calls), but will probably work fine in most cases.
So in your example code constint is interpreted as the name of a typedef and it's the job of the semantic analysis phase to realize that no typedef with that name exists.
